# innerhtml string to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

Is it possible to insert html into classes like so? It's not working and I have no errors in the console.

```
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>

<script>
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var yearTarget = document.getElementsByClassName("yearTarget");
    yearTarget.innerHTML = currentYear;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object. You have to either specify index or iterate through all the elements to set `innerHTML` individually:

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var yearTarget = document.getElementsByClassName("yearTarget");
[...yearTarget].forEach(function(el){
  el.innerHTML = currentYear;
});
```

```html
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>
<p class="caption">Copyright &copy; <span class="yearTarget"></span></p>
```

Comment: "[...yearTarget]" refused to go through the compiler, but it did the job. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @chilledMonkeyBrain, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")is selecting all the elements in webpage as array therefore you have to use [0]

```
yearTarget[0].innerHTML = currentYear;
```